# OpenCV Visual Studio 2010 - RC6034 Error (DLL Hell?)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, dll

[ Add HTTP:// to the beginning of picture links to make them work for you. ] [ All Steps here were done with both Release and Debug versions. The pictures shown only display debug-related information. ]

OpenCV 2.1.0 does not work properly with Visual Studio 2010 on my computer when it begins to load _Video files with the opencv_ffmpeg Dynamic Link Library_. A number of problems have arisen, specifically with my attempts to get the libraries and such to link for my use in applications. 99% of the errors I've encountered I've solved, save one:

i52.tinypic.com/2yxhmrq.jpg

Error Text:

`R6034
An Application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library without using a manifest. This is an unsupported way to load Visual C++ DLLs. You need to modify your application to build with a manifest. For more information, please see the "Visual C++ Libraries a SHared Side-by-Side Assemblies" topic in the production documentation.


(Press Retry to debug the application)`

Abort | Retry | Ignore

The error spawns from this source code:

```
 #include <cv.h>
 #include <cxcore.h>
 #include <highgui.h>

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "Missile.avi" );
  IplImage* frame;
  while (1) {
   frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
   if( !frame ) break;
   cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
   char c = cvWaitKey(33);
   if( c == 27 ) break;
  }
  cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
  cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
 }
```

Missile.avi is in the application's directory (using the full path still generates the same error, so it's not a File-Not-Found error).

Here's a checklist of everything I've done so far:

1. Attempt to follow the guides put in place by the OpenCV Wiki (opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B_VS2010). Using the pre-built install binaries for VS2008 did -not- work for me.
2. After much googling and reading online, I saw that people obtained success by compiling the libraries themselves after doing a MAKE operation from the source code using CMake. So, I compiled the OpenCV 2.1.0 from scratch using CMake 2.8.2 (gui) to Generate the Visual Studio 2010 OpenCV Solution. It was generated with the Cmake Option specified: BUILD_AS_SHARED_LIBS [YES]. The Solution was able to build in VS2010 with 0 fails on any of the projects.
3. Put all the appropriate files into the VC++ Directories under the new Visual Studio 2010 property sheet:
   i53.tinypic.com/2mxlrpg.jpg
   i54.tinypic.com/2rcbl9j.jpg
4. Preserve the required Visual Studio ".pdb" files required for Debugging. This was one of the initial errors when I simply used the Installed Binaries from the OpenCV Wiki - I needed to have .PDB files in order to use  the "Debug" mode.
   i56.tinypic.com/oh2tco.jpg

5a. Completing Number 4 allowed me to use the following OpenCV-based code without any issues:

```
    #include <cv.h>
    #include <cxcore.h>
    #include <highgui.h>

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("funny-pictures-cat-goes-pew.jpg");
        cvNamedWindow("Image:",1);
        cvShowImage("Image:",img);

        cvWaitKey();
        cvDestroyWindow("Image:");
        cvReleaseImage(&img);

        return 0;
    }
```

5b. The current problem arose when I began compiling code that required use of video files - MOV, AVI, MP4, etc (see code block at top of question). Due to linking the Source Code in the VC++ Directories properties, source code in cvwrap32.cpp that made use of the LoadLibrary function seemed to cause the error: i51.tinypic.com/69kgg7.jpg

1. The error stated that the loaded library did not have a Manifest (if my reading of the error shown in the picture up top was correct). So, I made sure that every library, when originally generated with CMake 2.8.2 (gui) and compiled in VS2010 had an ".manifest" file. Sure enough, each library had an (LibName).embed.manifest and a (LibName)manifest.rc. I even moved them into the application directory where the current application's .PDB, Manifest, and .ILK files were. The error still stated that the Library I was loading did not have a manifest.
2. As a last paranoia effort, I went through every project in the OpenCV VS2010 Solution to make sure /YES was on for Manifest Generation. It was.
3. Ran a depends.exe Dependency test. All required DLLs are present (all the msvcr90.dlls, etc).

That's as far as I got, before everything went to hell. I can't seem to correct this error, because the opencv_ffmpeg210.dll which LoadLibrary is calling from cvwrap32.cpp apparently does not have Manifest Data within it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Computer Specs: Windows 7 Ultimate x86 (32-bit). Compiling with Visual Studio 2010 with Visual C++.

Comment: NOTE: checked the name of the DLL that caused the breaking and erroring. It is indeed "opencv_ffmpeg210d.dll" (take away the d, and you get the same problem in the Release Version).

Comment: Can't see why somebody -1 this. Accurately described, so +1 to even the field.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your post, I knew that I wasn't going crazy.  I had almost the exact same issue when running .avi files through the EHCI head tracker (Google summer of code project).  I was able to track live video fine, but running the code on movie files generated the R6403 error.  In some cases, I could bypass the error and the code was working (similar to the 'one frame' shown case).  I had built my OpenCV from the source, which had taken me from not being able to run the hello-world to being able to run that and the EHCI sample code.  I kept searching and eventually found this person's opencv_ffmpeg210d.dll file : http://code.google.com/p/opencvthesis/source/browse/trunk/Capture_Estimator/Capture_Estimator/opencv_ffmpeg210d.dll?r=14

I replaced the dll generated by Cmake/VisStudio 2010 (not sure, not really an expert on coding at this level).  Voila!  Now EHCI works with video files without the R6403 error message.

Thought I should pass along the solution.  Maybe you guys can figure out what was wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run through [OpenCV-2.1.0 Visual C++ 2010 on Windows 7](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B_VS2010) to make sure it works.  It does not seem like you should have to build the OpenCV binaries yourself?

Comment: I have tried this already. It does not work when I try to use opencv_ffmpeg210d.dll , which is why I had to build the libraries myself.

Comment: @Jyoyi - do you have the same problem with the release binary (minus the 'd')?

Comment: When I use the Release binary, it just throws an error (again at the same LoadLibrary line of code, with an Access Violation). I have paralleled doing all the above steps and tests with the Release as well.

Comment: @Jyoti - have you tried the OpenCV wiki for this?  Sounds like a problem with their shipped binaries, maybe others have hit it?  VS2010 is not exactly an edge case.

Comment: I've hit the wiki for the install guides, and numerous searches (Google, in-wiki) didn't reveal much information. I only came to StackOverflow after I had exhausted all my option; for most people, it seemed building the binaries with Cmake fixed all their issues. For me, it did initially with the second block of code I put in my question above that only created an image. The problem came when I wanted to process a .AVI video using OpenCV.

Comment: Does that DLL load any others that might be the real problem? Try running `depends.exe` on it.

Comment: This post suggests copying the DLLs to \winnt\system32. Might be worth a try?  http://electronic-salad.blogspot.com/2010/03/install-opencv20-for-windows.html

Comment: I tried copying all my DLLs into Windows\system32. Even when opencv_ffmpeg210d.dll gets processed from system32, the manifest error is still present and an access violation is still called on Debug and Release versions (respectively). I'm still not sure what to do.

Comment: I edited the question to make it easier to read and to show all the steps I've taken thus far. Still no luck working with the code yet.